# "Show me other ways to activate" is disabled?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, activation

I have installed an instance of Win Server 2008 R2 on a Virtual machine.
This machine is purposefully on an isolated environment (no internet) for testing purposes.

I need to activate the machine and I have my MSDN key ready to go.
I just ran through the same steps with a Windows 7 VM, and was able to register using an automated telephone service from Microsoft.

With Windows Server 2008, I can see the same option to register using this service, but it is greyed out:

[image]

Google pointed me to people experiencing this issue but the only workarounds I saw where to use the internet (not an option for me).

Does anyone know how to enable this option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and run `slui 4`. That will start the "Activate by Phone" option manually.

Comment: didn't work. It's still grayed out

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, they posted the [exact solution on the Core Team blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-activate-windows-server-2008-core-edition-with-mak-key-over-the-phone.aspx).  Unfortunately, its not as pretty as it used to be.  Good luck!

---

For posterity's sake:

> After Windows Server 2008 Core Edition is installed do the following
>   at a cmd prompt
>
> 1. Install your MAK key using slmgr.vbs      `slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`      Where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is
>      your 5x5 MAK key supplied by Microsoft
> 2. View your Installation ID      `slmgr.vbs -dti`      Tip: The Installation ID is a 9x6 number. An easy way to split it up so it is
>      easier to read back to the phone activation system is to hit CTRL-C to
>      copy the contents of the dialogue box and paste into notepad. In
>      notepad it will be broken out into the 9x6 groups and easier to read.
> 3. Determine the phone number for your region:      `notepad %systemroot%\system32\slui\phone.inf`
> 4. Call the number for your region and follow the prompts to activate (as per normal). Type it into your notepad with no dashes so you can
>      paste it into the next step
> 5. Activate with your Confirmation ID      `slmgr.vbs –atp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`    Note: The –atp
>      option is only available when you have installed a MAK or retail key

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I would, but the steps are long and detailed, and contain a lot of specific information, so I didn't really want to clutter the answer--regardless, added as quoted text.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is you register your OVA image online and then import it to an off-line environment.

Ss for the registration you run in windows help system "how to activate windows":
 it will bring you the link to a dialogue to activate it, click OK and it will say activated for 180 days (after connecting to windows.com most likely).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP said he can't use the Internet, and wants to enable the greyed-out option.